# Instagram Widget Sizing - pictures not the same size

Tags: widget, instagram, blogger

I have an Instagram widget on my Blogger (pic below) - I'd like it to display the same squire sized pictures instead of what it's doing right now. Which part of the code below should I be changing? Would love to learn.

**Below is the code in my theme:**

```
/** Instagram widget support **/
.instag ul.thumbnails > li {
    width:30% !important;
}
.instag ul.thumbnails > li img:hover {
    opacity:.8;
}
.instag ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    border-bottom:none;
}
.pllexislider ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

**Below is the code for the HTML/Java script Gadget:**

```
<div id='instafeed' />
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

var feed = new Instafeed({
get: 'user',
userId: 16550415,
limit:6,
sortBy:'random',
accessToken: '16550415.8f4c5bf.ce58aa2b5d99494f8a2350b5b7315773',
template: '<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="insta-likes"><div style="display: table; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><span style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; width: 100%;">{{likes}} <i class="fa fa-heart"></i><br/>{{comments}} <i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span></div></div></a></li>',
resolution: 'standard_resolution'
});
feed.run();

//]]>
</script></div>
```

Instagram Widget - Current State
 [image: preview]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [**instafeedjs**](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js#standard-options) you have 3 options for `resolution` key:

- `thumbnail` -  150x150
- `low_resolution` - 306x306
- `standard_resolution` - 612x612

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thank you! I changed it to thumbnail and it works - images are now displaying the same sizes. However, is it possible to make them bigger? I now have these gaps between the images that I'm not sure how to get rid of.

Comment: Hi @MonicaPang thank you. the css styles you've provided in question are incomplete. Could you send your blog's link?